# how manage proper way to implement Countdown Timer for two players in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am a newbie for react js. how to manage two Countdown timers first start and second is stop after 5-second interval second start and first stop.

it work for single Clock successful but add two clocks then first only start and not stop while second not start I don't know how do this ?.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       isActive: true
    };
  }
 componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this.randomCallObject();
    }, 5000);
  }
  randomCallObject() {
      this.setState({
      Active: !this.state.isActive
    });
  }
  render() {
     let clock= {
          time: 150,
          isActive:this.state.isActive
        }
    let clock2= {
          time: 100,
          isActive:!this.state.isActive
        }
    return (
     <div className="container">
        <Clcok ClockData={clock}/>
        <Clcok ClockData={clock2}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
import React, { Component } from "react";
const TOTAL_MINUTES = 60;
export default class ClockComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      time: props.ClockData.time,
      isActive: props.ClockData.isActive
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { isActive } = this.state;
    if (isActive === true) {
      this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        const { time } = this.state;
        if (time > 0) {
          this.setState({
            time: time - 1
          });
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }
   render() {
    const { time } = this.state;
    let minutes ="" + Math.floor((time % (TOTAL_MINUTES * TOTAL_MINUTES))/ TOTAL_MINUTES);
    let seconds = "" + Math.floor(time % TOTAL_MINUTES);
    if (isNaN(minutes) || isNaN(seconds)) {
      return null;
    }
    if (minutes.length === 1) {
      minutes = `0${minutes}`;
    }
    if (seconds.length === 1) {
      seconds = `0${seconds}`;
    }
    return (
     <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-1">
        <div> 
            {minutes}:{seconds}
       </div>
        </div>
       </div>
     );
  }
}
```

when clock data comes from props so take simple objects when isActive flag is true then clock timer on when isActive false then timer stop

Answer (score 2):

To learn how to handle `setInterval` with React, I suggest you read the following blog post by [Dan Abramov](https://mobile.twitter.com/dan_abramov):

[Making setInterval Declarative with React Hooks](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)

In it, he explains how to use `setInterval` using `React Hooks` and also how to do it using a `class` component. On the post, there is also a link to a [`CodeSandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/embed/l240mp2pm7) example where you can see it in action.

What I did was create another `CodeSandbox` where you can see how you could apply this example to run multiple timers:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/timers-l6me1

I've used `React Hooks` in the example because they don't require a lot of code.

I hope it helps.

**edit #1**

Here is an example of a `Counter` component taken directly from the mentioned article, and adapted to fit the latter example.

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
    delay: 1000,
    isRunning: true
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ...this.state, ...props };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, this.state.delay);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.delay !== this.state.delay) {
      this.startInterval();
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  startInterval = () => {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, this.state.delay);
    console.log(this.interval);
  };

  tick = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    });
  };

  handleDelayChange = e => {
    this.setState({ delay: Number(e.target.value) });
  };

  toggleCounter = () => {
    console.log(this.state.isRunning);
    if (this.state.isRunning) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    } else {
      this.startInterval(this.state.delay);
    }
    this.setState({
      count: 0,
      isRunning: !this.state.isRunning
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      state: { isRunning, delay, count },
      toggleCounter,
      handleDelayChange
    } = this;

    return (
      <>
        <h1>{count}</h1>
        <input value={delay} onChange={handleDelayChange} />
        <button onClick={toggleCounter}>{isRunning ? "stop" : "start"}</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thx @guzmonne.any other solution without react hook?and i don't manage two timer react js

Comment: As I mentioned, on Dan Abramov's article there is an example on how to use this with a class component. I have included it in the answer and have made another example so you can see it in action: [here it is](https://codesandbox.io/embed/class-set-intervals-f4gqo)